# Element changes size on different screens

Tags: android, libgdx, position

I got this ImageButton that´s placed in a Table and added as an actor in a stage. It looks great on my phone, but when I run on my tablet the buttons is both too large and out of position. And I´ve declared a viewport on that stage like this(I´ve tried with different types of viewports aswell):

```
stageButton = new Stage(new ExtendViewport(screenWidth, screenHeight));
```

Then this is the resize method:

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {



    stageButton.getViewport().update(width, height, true);

    table.setBounds(backButtonW, backButtonH, buttonSizew, buttonSizeH);
    stageText.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    view.update(width, height);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2, camera.viewportHeight/2, 0);
    //camera.update();
}
```

And I´ve simply set the size and position like this:

```
public static  float buttonSizeH = 110;
public static  float buttonSizew = 110;
table.add(btnArrow).pad(30).size(buttonSizew, buttonSizeH);
    table.add(btnFB).size(buttonSizew, buttonSizeH);

    table.setBounds(backButtonW, backButtonH, buttonSizew, buttonSizeH);
```

If it matters this is how I set my camera with the viewport:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    view = new StretchViewport(screenWidth, screenHeight,camera);
    view.apply();

    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2, camera.viewportHeight/2, 0);
```

Comment: That's going to happen.  You're working in pixel sizes, and pixels are not the same size on all devices.  You shouldn't be using fixed sizes on Android, and if you are you need to be prepared for it to look different on different devices.  This guide isn't using your game engine, but it should give you an idea of the kind of issues you'll need to keep in mind with your UI design:   http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: No I would rather do it the right way. How should I define the sizes if not using pixels?

Comment: Making applications run uniformly on a wide array of devices is a large part of Android development. You should look into the difference between resolution, pixels, and pixel density.

Comment: Ok thanks I will and have started. Have converted my camera etc so it´s not declared in pixels anymore. But still to my problem with these buttons. They still appear out of the screen on my tablet.